# Solve the IVP $y'' + xy' - 4y = 0 y(0) = 2 , y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Solve the IVP $$y'' + xy' - 4y = 0, y(0) = 2 , y'(0) = 0$$

I tried power series solution and I found this equation

$$2(1+ 4x^2 - x^4 +\frac{1}{6}x^6-\frac{1}{48} x^8 + \dots).$$

However this answer is not accepted because I cannot write like that since it is webwork homework. Am I doing something wrong? Can you help me to solve the problem please?

Comment: If you need more details, I can add my solution

Comment: You have made mistakes as you don't satisfy either IC.

Comment: Using power series should work, just calculate the coefficients carefully. The final answer can be written using sigma notation if you end up with infinite sum.

Comment: Sorry about that. I made a calculation mistake. I found that error and solved the problem. The answer is $2+4x^2+2/3x^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by writing

$$y(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j.$$

Then

$$y''(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty j(j-1)a_jx^{j-2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)(j+2)a_{j+2}x^j$$

and

$$xy'(x)=x\sum_{j=0}^\infty ja_jx^{j-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty ja_jx^j.$$

Plugging this into the ODE we get

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \bigl((j+1)(j+2)a_{j+2}+ja_j-4a_j\bigr)x^j=0.$$

This gives us the recursion formula

$$a_{j+2}=-\frac{j-4}{(j+1)(j+2)}a_j.$$

It is immediately clear that $a_j=0$ if $j\geq6$ and $j$ is even. Furthermore, the initial conditions give us $a_0=2$ and $a_1=0$, from which it follows that $a_j=0$ if $j$ is odd. We thus only have to compute $a_2$ and $a_4$, which, by plugging into the formula above, we get as $a_2=4$ and $a_4=\frac{2}{3}$. It follows that

$$y(x)=2+4x^2+\frac{2}{3}x^4.$$